# javax.mail.SendFailedException, Can't get local hostname

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-mail

```
    >>>>>Sending data QUIT<<<<<<
    javax.mail.SendFailedException: Send failure (javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't get local hostname.  Please correctly configure JDK/DNS or set mail.smtp.localhost)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:163)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:48)
        at pl.intibs.logic.tools.EmailSender.sendEmail(EmailSender.java:56)
        at pl.intibs.paad.components.SampleMeasurementComponent.buttonClick(SampleMeasurementComponent.java:293)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
        at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)
        at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
        at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:977)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:393)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:61)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:168)
        at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:291)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:184)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:92)
        at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1408)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:350)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't get local hostname.  Please correctly configure JDK/DNS or set mail.smtp.localhost
        at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport.getLocalHost(SMTPTransport.java:1942)
        at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendEhlo(SMTPTransport.java:1870)
        at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendHandshake(SMTPTransport.java:1828)
        at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:393)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:242)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:85)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:70)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:94)
        ... 46 more
    >>>>>Sending data QUIT<<<<<<
    javax.mail.SendFailedException: Send failure (javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't get local hostname.  Please correctly configure JDK/DNS or set mail.smtp.localhost)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:163)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:48)
        at pl.intibs.logic.tools.EmailSender.sendEmail(EmailSender.java:56)
        at pl.intibs.paad.components.SampleMeasurementComponent.buttonClick(SampleMeasurementComponent.java:293)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
        at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)
        at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
        at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:977)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:393)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:61)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:168)
        at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:291)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:184)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:92)
        at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1408)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:350)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't get local hostname.  Please correctly configure JDK/DNS or set mail.smtp.localhost
        at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport.getLocalHost(SMTPTransport.java:1942)
        at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendEhlo(SMTPTransport.java:1870)
        at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendHandshake(SMTPTransport.java:1828)
        at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:393)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:242)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:85)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:70)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:94)
        ... 46 more

    public class EmailSender {
static String from = "account@int.pan.wroc.pl"; 
        private static String footer = "\n\n________________________________________________________\nJest to automatyczna wiadomość, proszę nie odpowiadać."+
                                       "\nThis is an automated message, please do not reply."; //stopka dodawana do każdego maila

        public static void sendEmail(String to, String subject, String messageText) throws AddressException, MessagingException {

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mserv3.int.pan.wroc.pl");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); 
            props.put("mail.smtp.password", "pass");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    //      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
            Message simpleMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

            InternetAddress fromAddress = null;
            InternetAddress toAddress = null;

                fromAddress = new InternetAddress(from);
                toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);

                simpleMessage.setFrom(fromAddress);
                simpleMessage.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
                simpleMessage.setSubject(subject);
                simpleMessage.setText(messageText);

                Transport.send(simpleMessage);   // Exception here      

        }
    }
```

I have problem. My code work good on my localhost machine. But when I deploy .war on server It can't send email. I don't know why.
Server is in the same network and ping with succes. mserv3.int.pan.wroc.pl So it's not problem with DNS.

My local dev machine: Ubuntu 14.04 + Tomcat 7
Server: CentOS 6 + Tomcat 7

Answer (score 1):

The stacktrace tells you the cause of the problem:

> Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't get local hostname.  Please correctly configure JDK/DNS or set mail.smtp.localhost

It seems, as if JavaMail is not able to determine the name of the host it is running on. Try the advices in the exception.

What is the result of the following statment?

```
bash> cat /etc/hostname
```

If it is impossible to set a hostname or get a name via DNS, then try to use the property `mail.smtp.localhost`.

[Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.geronimo.javamail/geronimo-javamail_1.4_provider/1.1/org/apache/geronimo/javamail/transport/smtp/SMTPTransport.java#1924) is the source code of the failing method. Perhaps the JavaDoc of the called [`#getHostName()`-method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/net/InetAddress.java#493) is helpful:

> Gets the fully qualified domain name for this IP address. Best effort method, meaning we may not be able to return the FQDN depending on the underlying system configuration.
>
> If there is a security manager, this method first calls its checkConnect method with the hostname and -1 as its arguments to see if the calling code is allowed to know the hostname for this IP address, i.e., to connect to the host. If the operation is not allowed, it will return the textual representation of the IP address.

Comment: Also, based on the exception message, I suspect you're using the GNU version of JavaMail that comes with many Linux systems.  You might want to switch to the [JavaMail reference implementation from Oracle](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

Answer (score 1):

My server hostname

```
bash> hostname
vm10.int.pan.wroc.pl
```

I add:

props.put("mail.smtp.localhost", "vm10.int.pan.wroc.pl");

and now it work, but I don't understand why. I have to share my .war. People should not have to edit this on every machine with CentOS 6.